# Float: Right Pushes Table to the Left

Tags: html, css

Ok, so I have several sections to a webpage that I am making.

There's a fieldset at the top, and then beneath that I have two forms, one standard, on the left, and another form that I am trying to make go on the right.

Underneath that, there SHOULD be a table.

Instead, when I put a div around the second form and give it the float: right property, the second form goes to the right of the table.

How do I keep it on the right side of the screen, but ABOVE the table in question?

Comment: Maybe some image or code can help.

Comment: jsfiddle would be good, you can edit css and html in it or a link to a demo page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap both forms into a DIV, and then have each form in its own div. Then, have the form you want to float right be ABOVE the other in the markup.

```
<div id='container'>
  <div id='divForm2' style="float:right;">
     <form id='form2' >
  </div>
  <div id='divForm1' >
     <form id='form1' >
  </div>
</div>

<table>
<tr....
```

Basically, an element floats to the right of the element that it preceds.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to clear your floats.]

```
psuedocode:
<div>
  <form1 float: left; />
  <form2 float: right; />
  <br style="clear: both;" />
  <table />
<div>
```